# Custom TabBar with UIButtons

Tags: uibutton, instance-methods

First: Sorry for my bad English!

I have a class in which I create UIButton. The UIButton I add a UIView. In the ViewController I would like to add these custom tabbar. This works well so far. However, there are problems with addTarget: action: forControlEvents: - How can I run from the ViewController an instance method in the class? The class is of type NSObject. My code:

```
TabBar *tabBar = [[TabBar alloc] init];
    [tabBar tabBarButton];
    [tabBar.home addTarget:tabBar action:@selector(switchView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBar.tabView];
```

And here is my Class:

```
@implementation TabBar
@synthesize tabView, home, list, charts, favorits, more;

-(void)tabBarButton{

    tabView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 360, 320,56)];

    home = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 43, 56)];
    list = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(63, 0, 40, 56)];
    charts = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(123, 0, 49, 56)];
    favorits = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(192, 0, 66, 56)];
    more = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(278, 0, 42, 56)];

    [home setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [list setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"liste.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [charts setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"charts.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [favorits setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [more setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    home.tag = 1;
    list.tag = 2;
    charts.tag = 3;
    favorits.tag = 4;
    more.tag = 5;


    [tabView addSubview:home];
    [tabView addSubview:list];
    [tabView addSubview:charts];
    [tabView addSubview:favorits];
    [tabView addSubview:more];

}

-(void)switchView{
    NSLog(@"hi");
}
```

When I start the app, it crashes immediately when I press one button.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an unrecognized selector error, you might try:

```
[tabBar.home addTarget:tabBar action:@selector(switchView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Note the colon behind action:@selector(switchView:)